# Assign different domain url to subdomain

Tags: subdomain, plesk

I have my site's domain example1.com and I also have the following domains: example2.com and example3.com
I need to create two subdomains in example1.com (subdomain2.example1.com & subdomain3.example1.com) that will point respectively to example2.com and example3.com

How can I do that in PLESK?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

There 3 ways:

- create domain aliases subdomain2.example1.com for example2.com and subdomain3.example1.com for example3.com
- create subdomains and than change hosting type of this subdomains to standard forwarding
- create subdomains for example1.com and than place index.html to /httpdocs of each subdomain with following content(check [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)):

> ```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://exampleX.com/'">
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```